# Excel - How do I find the index/position of the nth word of a string?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a cell with a long paragraph, and I’m trying to create a formula to find the index of the first or last letter of the nth word.

For example, if my string is: `This is sentence 1. This is sentence 2.` and I wanted the position of the 3rd word, the formula should return 9 (position of the “s” in “sentence” of) or 16 (position of the final “e” in sentence).

Further to the example, if I wanted the position of the 4th word, the formula should return 18 (position of the “1”) or 19 (position of the period).

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem.  What are you planning to do with that number?  If you want to return the nth word, you don't need the position.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I’m trying to extract a substring between two positions. Do you think this is the right approach?

Comment: That is one method, but there are easier (and easier to understand and troubleshoot, in my opinion), other methods.  See my Answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Take the **third word**.

The third word will occur after the **second** space.  Will will find the second space amd them add one:

```
=FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",CHAR(1),2))+1
```

[image]

So in the above example, the third word begins at string position #8.

**NOTE**

To get the position of the 12<sup>th</sup> word, we would use:

```
=FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",CHAR(1),11))+1
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

To extract the nth word of a string, it seems logical to turn the sentence into an array and then extract the nth element of that array.

if you have a Windows version of Excel 2013+, you can create an XML where each node is a word, and then use the  `FILTERXML` to extract the appropriate node:

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A2)," ","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s[" & WordNum & "]")
```

If you have a MAC version, or earlier version, the formula is more complicated. You create an Array where each element is a word, and then use the `INDEX` function to return the appropriate element.

```
=INDEX(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A2)," ",REPT(" ",99)),seq_99,99)),WordNum)
```

where `seq_99` is a Named Formula that refers to:

```
=IF(ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1,1):INDEX($A:$A,255,1))=1,1,(ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1,1):INDEX($A:$A,255,1))-1)*99)
```

[image]